# Raspberry Pi, Windows 10 IoT, Visual Studio Update 2, Python won't deploy: Cannot connect to remote debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

With the following setup I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" program.

- Windows IoT
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Visual Studio 2010 with all of the relevant addons

The error that I'm getting is:

> Cannot connect to remote debugger.

I've tried the following solutions:

- Use powershell to start msvsmon (file cannot be found)
- Followed the guide here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AppDeployment.htm#python

I've been searching and trying to fix this and got nowhere. What new things can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Only Visual Studio 2015 is supported (probably typing mistake by you). I wouldn't waste time on "Stable" release of Windows 10 Core - I had to many problems. Go for Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm

Answer (score 1):

Verify you have the Remote Machine "Authentication Mode" set to `Universal (Unencrypted Protocol)`. This can sometimes cause problems with the debugger.

Check out Step 3 here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AppDeployment.htm